# How to load Image progressively so that ImageObserver work?

Tags: java, image, swing, graphics, progressive-download

There is `ImageObserver` ability in `Graphics.drawImage()` method. What is the easiest way to see this in action? I guess `ImageIO.read()` returns `BufferedImage` so it is all in memory. How to get partially loaded images so that observer called?

Comment: Try using any method that returns an `Image`, something like [Toolkit.getImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getImage%28java.net.URL%29) might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to call the image observer.  If you're calling the `drawImage` method and the image is still processing, it'll start using the `ImageObserver`.  Scaling is one example which will cause the image to generally be processing.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ImageObserverDemo extends Box{

    Image bi;
    Image bi2;
    Dimension d = new Dimension(300,200);

    public ImageObserverDemo() {
        super(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);        
        try {
            bi = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/0304/bluemarble2k_big.jpg"));
            bi = bi.getScaledInstance(100, 100, BufferedImage.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            bi2 = new BufferedImage(bi.getWidth(this), bi.getHeight(this), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            bi2.getGraphics().drawImage(bi, 0, 0, this);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean imageUpdate(final Image img, int infoflags, int x, int y,
            int width, int height) {

        boolean result = true;
        if((infoflags | ImageObserver.FRAMEBITS) == ImageObserver.FRAMEBITS){
            result = false;
        } else if((infoflags | ImageObserver.ALLBITS) == ImageObserver.ALLBITS){
            result = false;
        }

        if(result){
            System.out.println("Image incomplete");
        } else{
            System.out.println("Complete");
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return d;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new ImageObserverDemo());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```